# Searching ONLY "completed" items in inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

Here is my existing code- I need some help counting ONLY items in the inbox that have been marked as "completed"

```
Sub HowManyEmails()

    Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim EmailCount As Integer
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        On Error Resume Next
        Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Investment Central").Folders("Inbox")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Exit Sub
        End If

    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count

    MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount, , "email count"

    Dim dateStr As String
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim msg As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set myItems = objFolder.Items
    myItems.SetColumns ("SentOn")
    ' Determine date of each message:
    For Each myItem In myItems
        dateStr = GetDate(myItem.SentOn)
        If Not dict.Exists(dateStr) Then
            dict(dateStr) = 0
        End If
        dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1
    Next myItem

    ' Output counts per day:
    msg = ""
    For Each o In dict.Keys
        msg = msg & o & ": " & dict(o) & " items" & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox msg

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetDate(dt As Date) As String
    GetDate = Year(dt) & "-" & Month(dt)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Items.Restrict` on FlagStatus = 1 (olFlagComplete).

```
Set myItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict("[FlagStatus] = 1")
```